# Vuelidate common validation logic

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I am currently studying front-end javascript development and current doing a personal project using VueJS, Vuetify and Vuelidate.

I have a simple question.

I have two text fields as below.

```
  <v-layout wrap>
    <v-flex>
      <v-text-field
        label="First Name"
        maxlength="20"
        v-model.trim="firstName"
        :error-messages="firstNameErrors"
        @input="$v.firstName.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.firstName.$touch()"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex>
      <v-text-field
        label="Last Name"
        v-model.trim="lastName"
        maxlength="20"
        :error-messages="lastNameErrors"
        @input="$v.lastName.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.lastName.$touch()"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

I have a vuelidate written in the computed hook as below.

```
  computed: {
    firstNameErrors () {
      const errors = []
      if (!this.$v.firstName.$dirty) return errors
      !this.$v.firstName.required && errors.push('First Name is required')
      return errors
    },
    lastNameErrors () {
      const errors = []
      if (!this.$v.lastName.$dirty) return errors
      !this.$v.lastName.required && errors.push('Last Name is required')
      return errors
    }
```

The code works fine and does what is supposed to do, generate validation errors, "required" in my case.

My question is, I would like to include both validation error functions "firstNameErrors" and "lastNameErrors" under one function named "requiredErrors" rather than having two separate functions.

Code pen: https://codepen.io/pen/jebLgM

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not follow your logic but taking your request literally it may look like this:

```
 <v-layout wrap>
    <v-flex>
      <v-text-field
        label="First Name"
        maxlength="20"
        v-model.trim="firstName"
        :error-messages="requiredErrors"
        @input="$v.firstName.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.firstName.$touch()"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex>
      <v-text-field
        label="Last Name"
        v-model.trim="lastName"
        maxlength="20"
        :error-messages="requiredErrors"
        @input="$v.lastName.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.lastName.$touch()"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>

  computed: {
    requiredErrors () {
      const errors = []
      this.$v.firstName.$dirty 
        && !this.$v.firstName.required 
        && errors.push('First Name is required')
      this.$v.lastName.$dirty
        && !this.$v.lastName.required 
        && errors.push('Last Name is required')
      return errors
    }
```

## UPDATE

Yeah, that is why I said that I do not follow your logic (having the same message for both inputs). You can probably achieve what you want by `bind`-ing your function multiple times with different 1-st argument but the function can no longer be a method of your component (because those are already bound by Vue).

Maybe something like this:

```
<v-text-field
    label="First Name"
    maxlength="20"
    v-model.trim="firstName"
    :rules="requiredErrorsFirstName"
    @input="$v.firstName.$touch()"
    @blur="$v.firstName.$touch()"
  ></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
    label="Last Name"
    v-model.trim="lastName"
    maxlength="20"
    :rules="requiredErrorsLastName"
    @input="$v.lastName.$touch()"
    @blur="$v.lastName.$touch()"
  ></v-text-field>

computed:
{
  requiredErrorsFirstName ()
  {
    return [requiredErrors.bind(this,'firstName')];
  },
  requiredErrorsLastName ()
  {
    return [requiredErrors.bind(this,'lastName')];
  }
}

function requiredErrors(fieldName, fieldValue)
{
  switch(fieldName)
  {
    case 'firstName':
      return this.$v[fieldName].$dirty 
            && !this.$v[fieldName].required 
            ? 'First Name is required' : true;
    case 'lastName':
      return this.$v[fieldName].$dirty 
            && !this.$v[fieldName].required 
            ? 'Last Name is required' : true;   
  }
}
```

I personally think that this is ugly and would prefer having a separate computed property or method for each field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible to have one function with switch cases in it where you pass in the field to be checked as an argument and only process the switch case and return the validation error accordingly?

Comment: Also, I have updated the codepen according to your suggestion, now I get the "required" message on both inputs regardless of what's being touched. [codepen link](https://codepen.io/pen/jebLgM)